# count() in where clause from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to sql. I have two tables. I want to check the count of each tables, and then I want to select the number of counts when the counts of each tables are equal.

Here is my query;

```
$ratio = "SELECT count(*) AS ratio FROM live_agents,campaigns 
          WHERE live_agents.count(agent) = campaigns.count(id)";
```

NOTE : I know that the live_agents.count(agent) and campaigns.count(id) will not work. I am writing this line to clearly understand my situation. I want to count the number of rows of column agent in live_agents table and want to count the number of rows of column id in campaigns table.

Table `live_agents`:

```
agent
------
admin
user
staff
```

Table `campaigns`:

```
id
----
1
2
```

Expected output:

```
count
-------
2
```

Hope all of you understood my problem

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: If live_agents has 5 rows, and campaigns 3 rows - what will be the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use `LEAST()`:

```
SELECT LEAST( (SELECT Count(*) AS Ratio FROM live_agents),
              (SELECT Count(*) AS Ratio FROM campaigns)
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
SELECT Min(Ratio) Count FROM
(
   SELECT Count(*) AS Ratio FROM live_agents
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Count(*) AS Ratio FROM campaigns
)X
```